# What would be the word for people waiting for an important announcement?

Tags: single-word-requests

> "The winning lottery, that will decide the winner of $1 million lottery the rest have to pay for, is ..." says Tom, in front of _____ candidates.

What would be an appropriate word to use in place of the ____ ?

Anxious?

Expecting?

Answer (score 16):

**expectant** (*adj.*):

having or showing an excited feeling that something is about to happen, especially something good

> 'Mr Williams thanked everybody for their participation, before he announced the winners of the £25 prizes to the expectant crowd.'

*Source:* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 6):

**[with bated breath](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+bated+breath)**

> Eagerly or anxiously, as in "**we waited for the announcement of the
>   winner with bated breath**".

This expression literally means "holding one's breath" ( bate means "restrain").

- They listened *with bated breath* for the announcement about the winner.

(Cite- McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms/TFD)

> Search in Google and you'll find about the same number of hits for
>   'baited breath' as 'bated breath'.

From Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, we have:

- "The whole common room listened with baited breath."

> The earliest known citation of the phrase is from Shakespeare's
>   Merchant of enice, 1596:
>
> What should I say to you? Should I not say 'Hath a dog money? is it
>   possible A cur can lend three thousand ducats?' Or Shall I bend low
>   and in a bondman's key, With bated breath and whispering humbleness )

Comment: +1.  But "baited breath", no matter how popular,  is an _eggcorn_ for "bated breath".  It's probably so common because "bated" is no longer used in AmE except as part of that  _set phrase_.  We do still use "abated".

Answer (score 3):

[Anticipating](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/anticipate)?

> To anticipate something is to be expecting it. Your dog might be
>   waiting by the door, anticipating his next walk or squirrel chase.
>
> "Anticipating something" also often implies that **you are preparing to
>   take some action because of your expectations** — like when you
>   anticipate your chess opponent's next move and plan a counterattack.
>   The word anticipate can also mean "to come beforehand" — as in a
>   certain musical trend anticipating another. (Vocabulary.com)

Note that the bold part relates to people waiting for an important announcement.

Answer (score 2):

[Impatient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impatient) may convey the idea of something you are anxious about and can't wait to see the outcome:

> - Unable to wait patiently or tolerate delay; restless.

With a stronger connotation and depending on context you can use also:

[apprehensive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apprehensive):

> - uneasy or fearful about something that might happen.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: apprehensive.. that may seem to be that

Comment: Apprehensive is used when someone expects bad news.  Wouldn't the people be hoping for good news?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - as I said in me answer "with a stronger connotation and depending on context". It seems that the term requested may be applied to different situations.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ***waiting on tenterhooks***. The OED entry for this figurative use of *tenterhooks* is:

> c. to be on (the) tenterhooks              : i.e. in a state of
>   painful suspense or impatience: cf. tenter n.1 3b.
>
> 1748   T. Smollett Roderick Random II. xlv. 94,   I..left him upon the
>   tenter-hooks of impatient uncertainty.
>
> 1812   R. Wilson Private Diary (1861) I. 127   Until I reach the
>   imperial headquarters I shall be on tenter-hooks.
>
> 1897   Sat. Rev. 25 Dec. 754/1   The author keeps..the reader..on
>   tenterhooks.

Comment: Other common variations of this one include "waiting on the edge of your seat", or "waiting with bated breath". But this is a multiple word answer to a question explicitly looking for a single word, and this answer doesn't fit the asker's example in any shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed nobody mentioned **hopeful** so far.
Especially if you are waiting for something good that might happen, you will be full of hope it will happen to you.
**Expectant** (already supplied by other answers) might be a better fit in a more general context, but for the example given by the question **hopeful** is certainly a contender.